# meteor cordova image share app

Tags: image, cordova, meteor, camera, gallery

I am building a METEOR app where users can click/upload images using camera and gallery. And other users should be able to see the image and download it.

I have installed the following plugins :

cordova-plugin-camera@2.4.1,

cordova-plugin-file@4.3.3

Here's my code :

```
var cameraOptions = {
    quality: 100,
    previewDrag: false,
    sourceType: sourcetype,
    correctOrientation: true,
    allowEdit: true,
    saveToPhotoAlbum : true,
    mediaType : Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
    destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions
};
navigator.camera.getPicture(function cameraSuccess(fileURI){
    resolveLocalFileSystemURL(dataURL, function(entry) {
        Session.set('imgData', entry.toInternalURL());          
    });
}, function cameraError(error){
    Session.set('imgData', false);
}, cameraOptions);`
```

Session.get('imgData') is passed as img src (image not rendering though)

Not sure how to proceed though. Any insights??

PS: future tasks include iploading video, pdf, docs and other files too. So an answer that also helps with that would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for getting image.
this part is to get image.

```
function onCopySuccess(entry) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.image = entry.nativeURL;
    });
}
```

here is full code about take picture and get image.
You should install cordova-plugin-file plugin.

```
// 2
    var options = {
        destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, // Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
        allowEdit : false,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
    };

    // 3
    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {

        // 4
        onImageSuccess(imageData);

        function onImageSuccess(fileURI) {
            createFileEntry(fileURI);
        }

        function createFileEntry(fileURI) {
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileURI, copyFile, fail);
        }

        // 5
        function copyFile(fileEntry) {
            var name = fileEntry.fullPath.substr(fileEntry.fullPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            var newName = makeid() + name;

            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function(fileSystem2) {
                fileEntry.copyTo(
                    fileSystem2,
                    newName,
                    onCopySuccess,
                    fail
                );
            },
            fail);
        }

        // 6
        function onCopySuccess(entry) {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.image = entry.nativeURL;
            });
        }

        function fail(error) {
            console.log("fail: " + error.code);
        }     
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: what does makeid() in the function copyFIle(fileEntry) refer to?